# Retrofit2: null response when I try to get data from JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit, response

I want to get data from my JSON, I already convert using jsonschema2pojo and make the class name Login in my android project, and  but when I try to get data in my class it's still get null value.
Here is my code

**Login.java**

```
 @SerializedName("id_user")
    @Expose
    private String idUser;
    @SerializedName("id_role")
    @Expose
    private String idRole;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("id_peg")
    @Expose
    private Object idPeg;
    @SerializedName("id_pel")
    @Expose
    private String idPel;
```

**Loginactivity**

```
 public void login() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    LoginAPI api = retrofit.create(LoginAPI.class);

    Call<Login> call = api.Login(username, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
            response.body();
            Integer value=response.body().getValue();
            String message=response.body().getMessage();
            progress.dismiss();

            if(value==1){
                String email=response.body().getEmail();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Network Connection Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show the JSON structure. There might be a mismatch of data.

Comment: [[{"id_user":"10","id_role":"5","username":"komang","password":"komang","email":"komangarinanda@gmail.com","id_peg":null,"id_pel":"6"}]]

Comment: here is my JSON structure

Comment: @Kharisma pls post the full response, which getting from API ?

Comment: Its clear, already my mistake from JSON structure thanks

Comment: improved title and formatting

Answer (score 0):

Using both @Expose and @SerializedName might be the problem:

Either use:

```
@Expose
private String id_user;
```

or

```
@SerializedName("id_user")
private String idUser;
```

[This](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-how-to-ignore-fields-with-expose) might be of help.

**Edit**

Also I noticed that the response is an Array and not an Object! So the call will be like this:

```
Call<Login[]> call = api.Login(username, password);
```

The corresponding responses will also use Login[] instead of Login.

Comment: it will not create the problem